# Convert date '11/2/2014' (mm/d/yyyy) into timestamp in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to convert date '11/2/2014' into timestamp using Hive.
This date is in string format.
I tried many ways but I am getting NULL values.

Comment: To improve the question, please also include the code you written to convert

Comment: there is now direct udf you have to write custom udf..

Comment: DATE values are represented in the form YYYY-­MM-­DD. Example: DATE ‘2014-­12-­07’. Date ranges allowed are 0000-­01-­01 to 9999-­12-­31.

TIMESTAMP use the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]. 

cast(string as date)-- If the string is in the form ‘YYYY-MM-DD’, then a date value corresponding to that is returned. If the string value does not match this format, then NULL is returned.

source -http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-data-types-examples/

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax:

```
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<date_column>,'MM/dd/yyyy')) as TIMESTAMP)
```

You always need to go to unix_timestamp and then cast from unix timestamp to normal timestamp. It doesn't look great, but it works.

Just to check, it might be that your syntax is right but your format is wrong. Perhaps your format is dd/MM/yyyy? That is the reason why you should give us your attempts to get it work next time.

Comment: It worked fine. I was missing syntax. Thanks a ton :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using only String functions:

```
SELECT CAST(
         CONCAT(
           REGEX_REPLACE(
           REGEX_REPLACE( dirty_date
                        , '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$','$3-0$1-0$2')
                        , '-0([0-9][0-9])','-$1')
          , ' 00:00:00')
       AS TIMESTAMP)
FROM dirty_input
```